# UITableViewController (storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2, uitableview

I have Navigation controller as intial view which goes into view controller

now i have table view after this view

Nav controller > UI View Controller > Table view

Issue occurs here

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    MasterViewController2 *controller = (MasterViewController2 *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}
```

app builds and fails with this message

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e22df0'
```

any idea why its failing and crashing app even though there is no build errors or warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the class of your view controller in the storyboard to `MasterViewController2`. The exception is showing you that the object is of type `ViewController` with the message `'-[ViewController setManagedObjectContext:]:`. This is in the identity inspector (*View* → *Utilities* → *Show Identity Inspector* with your view controller selected).

Comment: i already have that set, the issue is passing ManagedObjectContext from UIViewController to UITableViewController where UIViewcontroller is not a rootViewController and i cant use UINavigationController or UITabbarcontroller.

if i remove the code
 UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    MasterViewController2 *controller = (MasterViewController2 *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
and just leave
return YES, code works but nothing is inserted into DB

Comment: Instead of adding the view controller do `NSLog(@"%@", [controller class]);`. If the class is not MasterViewController2, then you either don't have the class set in the storyboard, or your accessing something different from what you expect through the top view controller.

Comment: wbyoung thanks for the info i thought that would have been the case too as i could be missing core data wiring context from app delegate but i tried retrieving from app delegate as well as passing from appdelegate to view controllers stil no luck.

Comment: After your edits, your now having a different crash. Did the original problem get fixed? Your new problem is likely either a missing or improperly named entity or a missing model. It has nothing to do with the original question. I'd recommend asking this as a new question entirely.